# Consolidate function with wildcard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard

I want to consolidate the following function into something more eloquent.

Basically I want to get element by id like "title#" and push "#" into the function so that if you click on title#x you will ReverseDisplay link#xcontent.

Appreciate any advice thank you.

```js
document.getElementById("title1").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
     ReverseDisplay('link1content');
}

document.getElementById("title2").onclick = function() {myFunction1()};

function myFunction1() {
     ReverseDisplay('link2content');
}

document.getElementById("title3").onclick = function() {myFunction2()};

function myFunction2() {
     ReverseDisplay('link3content');
}

document.getElementById("title4").onclick = function() {myFunction3()};

function myFunction3() {
     ReverseDisplay('link4content');
}

document.getElementById("title5").onclick = function() {myFunction4()};

function myFunction4() {
     ReverseDisplay('link5content');
}

document.getElementById("title6").onclick = function() {myFunction5()};

function myFunction5() {
     ReverseDisplay('link6content');
}


document.getElementById("title7").onclick = function() {myFunction6()};

function myFunction6() {
     ReverseDisplay('link7content');
}

document.getElementById("title8").onclick = function() {myFunction7()};

function myFunction7() {
     ReverseDisplay('link8content');
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for classes, and not ids. Also in your example `function() {myFunction()}` is equivalent to `myFunction`. Edit: Also, your `myFunction` variable is being redefined multiple times, but since its a function declaration only the last one is used for all instances.

Comment: For the question specifically, what does your html look like?

Comment: what does `ReverseDisplay` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
const ReverseDisplay = x => console.log(x)

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="title"]'))
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () =>
     ReverseDisplay(`link${el.id.split('title').join('')}content`)))
```

```html
<div id="title1">title1</div>
<div id="title2">title2</div>
<div id="title3">title3</div>
```

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), so we have to use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to be able to use array methods like `forEach`. Then we add a click event listener to each element using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (see [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/3853934)). Using `split('title').join('')` we remove the `'title'` part from the ID and leave only the number. If you're wondering what are these `` ` `` and `=>`, see [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).